# how to make a copy of the result of a call

Tags: karate

Why does the following test not pass? I must be missing something fundamental about how copy works. It seems to have a reference to the json object and not a copy.

```
Feature: testing

  @one
  Scenario: one
    * def root = { name: 'inner' }

  Scenario: two
    * def a = call read('testing.feature@one')
    * copy b = a
    * set b.root.name = "copy"
    * match b.root.name == "copy"
    * match a.root.name == "called"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always un-wrap the results of `call`. The reason is that particular JSON object is "special" (a Java map) which does not follow the rules of `copy` - because you can have references to other Java objects. So this will work:

```
  @one
  Scenario: one
    * def root = { name: 'inner' }

  Scenario: two
    * def temp = call read('dev.feature@one')
    * def a = temp.root
    * copy b = a
    * set b.name = "copy"
    * match b.name == "copy"
    * match a.name == "inner"
```

Comment: So you answered my question and actually helped me to understand what is going on now. How do I perform a deep copy of the entire JSON object (all child maps) so that I can preserve a prior state? If you want a new example I can provide.

Comment: @MarkLindell yes do provide a new example - I'm curious as to why you want this also

Comment: I am trying to chain together multiple operations for an API that tests history of changes. I need a way to keep the original complete response object from the POST to compare later. Maybe I'm just going about this the wrong way.

Comment: @MarkLindell it looks good to me. you have stored each response into new variables, does it not work the way you expect ? if you can follow this process and replicate - that would help: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue