# Possible bug with deep copy of subfeature __arg

Tags: karate

When passing json to a subfeature * copy doesn't perform a deep copy and thus both instance variables are pointing to the same data.

I've verified * copy is indeed deep when the data is not passed to a subfeature.

Parent feature

```
  Feature: calling debug feature

    Scenario:
      * def jsonA = { a: "aValue", children: [{childA: "childAValue" }]}
      * def result = call read('Debug.feature') jsonA
```

Sub feature

```
Feature: debug

  Background:
    * def jsonA = __arg
    * copy jsonACopy = jsonA
    * set jsonACopy $.children[0].childA = 'childAValueUpdated'
    * print "TEST: -------------------", jsonA, jsonACopy

    Scenario:
      * match jsonACopy != jsonA
```

After updating the jsonACopy I would not expect jsonA to be modified.

```
15:58:10.517 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] TEST: ------------------- {
  "a": "aValue",
  "children": [
    {
      "childA": "childAValueUpdated"
    }
  ]
}
 {
  "a": "aValue",
  "children": [
    {
      "childA": "childAValueUpdated"
    }
  ]
}

15:58:10.519 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - assertion failed: path: $, actual: {a=aValue, children=[{"childA":"childAValueUpdated"}]}, NOT expected: {a=aValue, children=[{"childA":"childAValueUpdated"}]}, reason: all key-values matched
15:58:10.520 [main] ERROR com.intuit.karate - feature call failed: Debug.feature
arg: {a=aValue, children=[{"childA":"childAValueUpdated"}]}
Debug.feature:10 - path: $, actual: {a=aValue, children=[{"childA":"childAValueUpdated"}]}, NOT expected: {a=aValue, children=[{"childA":"childAValueUpdated"}]}, reason: all key-values matched
CallDebug.feature:6 -
Debug.feature:10 - path: $, actual: {a=aValue, children=[{"childA":"childAValueUpdated"}]}, NOT expected: {a=aValue, children=[{"childA":"childAValueUpdated"}]}, reason: all key-values matched
HTML report: (paste into browser to view) | Karate version: 0.9.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you confirm if this is the same issue as opened here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/708

You can also refer to this other answer on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55377608/143475

Also refer the open issue above - and do comment if you have any findings or suggestions to add.

For now, please workaround by doing a string conversion:

```
* def a = foo
* string b = foo
* json b = b
```

Comment: Yes, it looks like the same issue as 708 and I also confirmed the workaround applies for my scenario as well.